# how to get list of files on aws bucket with a specific pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking for a way to get the list of files with a specific pattern from aws. But it seems that it can not support it.

In detail:

I have a bucket in AWS that has several hundred thousand files in it and I am want to find that has a specific pattern. For example, I want to find all files that are "my*.txt" on the bucket and list them.

If I run this command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my_bucket/  --recursive > byBucketList.txt
```

Then I can search for my files in the text file and found where are they. But I am not able to run anything such as this:

```
 aws s3 ls s3://my_bucket/my*.txt  --recursive > byBucketList.txt
```

to only get the list of files that I am looking for.

Is there any way that I get the list of files with a specific pattern on an AWS bucket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly you can't do this with `s3 ls`. But you could possibly use [Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) along with **--dryrun** for commands that support filters. For example, for `s3 cp`:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket ./. --recursive --dryrun --exclude "*" --include "my*.txt"
```

> --dryrun (boolean) Displays the operations that would be performed using the specified command **without actually running them**.

This should print out all the objects that would be normally copied without `--dryrun` option.

Since you have a large bucket, you can **test** it out on small bucket just to get the feel of the command as its output is different then from `s3 ls`.

Answer (score 1):

mans you can achieve this using grep.

```
 aws s3 ls s3://my_bucket --recursive | grep -e 'my[A-Za-z0-9]*.txt' > byBucketList.txt
```

Comment: This is not a good solution as the list of all files which could be millions will be transferred to my PC before I can get the result.

Comment: What do you mean the files will be transferred to your PC? Are you not talking about the other comment using the cp I use ls

Comment: In your solution, the list of all files transferred from aws server to your pc and then grep filter them. In the cp solution, the filtering happens on the server and only the list of files that matches is transferred.

Comment: The files are not transferred to your computer with the ls operation, so I am not sure what you are talking about. This solution only returns the output of what is in the folders added bonus it includes the file size as well.

Comment: If you take the above command and modify it to  aws s3 ls s3://my_bucket --recursive | grep -e 'my[A-Za-z0-9]*.txt' | wc -l then you will get the number of items in your bucket that match but nothing is copied to your PC with this action.

Comment: The files don't copy, but the LISt is copied. If the list is very big, then you need to pay for egress cost. Please note that I am not speaking about transferring actual files, but the list of files.